# Deploy Scrapy project to remote Scrapyd service error

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

I tried to deploy a test Scrapy project to the remote Scrapyd server. I got the following error message in client side.

```
curl http://IP:6800/addversion.json -d project=test_project -d spider=quotes
{"status": "error", "message": "'version'", "node_name": "serverName"}
```

Error message in server-side

```
2018-11-13T12:22:22+0000 [_GenericHTTPChannelProtocol,0,IP Address] Unhandled Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/http.py", line 2190, in allContentReceived
        req.requestReceived(command, path, version)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/http.py", line 917, in requestReceived
        self.process()
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/server.py", line 199, in process
        self.render(resrc)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/server.py", line 259, in render
        body = resrc.render(self)
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/webservice.py", line 21, in render
        return JsonResource.render(self, txrequest).encode('utf-8')
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/utils.py", line 20, in render
        r = resource.Resource.render(self, txrequest)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/resource.py", line 250, in render
        return m(request)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/webservice.py", line 83, in render_POST
        version = txrequest.args[b'version'][0].decode('utf-8')
    exceptions.KeyError: 'version'
```

I checked both client and server sides, the Scrapy version are all 1.5.1. The python version are 2.7.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample `curl` command you shown earlier is not supposed to work. According to [the documentation](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#addversion-json), you'll also need:

1. A `version` argument, which is believed to be the cause of issue you experience now.
2. A `egg` argument containing the actual project code, otherwise `scrapyd` won't be able to receive it when you pass in only the project name and spider name.